# How to use paginate() on relationship and add fields to model object in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, dictionary, collections, relationship, pagination

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $comments = $post->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->transform(function ($item, $key) {
        $item->registered = $item->created_at->diffForHumans();
        return $item;
    });

    return view('blog_views.post')->with(['post' => $post, 'comments' => $comments]);
}
```

I want to add paginate(5) on $comments before return it to view and keep this values accessible in the view.

```
{{ $comment->user->name }}    relationship returning the creator name of the comment
{{ $comment->registered }}    get the created field in controller

And the new one -> paginate links

{{$comments->links()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an accessor for your `registered` attribute and remove the need for iterating a collection manually to add it:

```
// Comment model

public function getRegisteredAttribute()
{
    return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}

// Controller

public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    $comments = $post->comments()
        ->with('user')
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(5);

    return view('blog_views.post', [
        'post' => $post,
        'comments' => $comments,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you a lot. It was rly that simple ...